# compute compactly supported cohomology of a space

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

Given space $M=R^2/0$ ($R^2$ excluding origin), how to compute compactly supported de Rham cohomology of M, in notation, $H^*(c(M))$?

I am thinking of raising a vector v in $R^2$ with |v| at most some fixed length r, but this setup is not compact once you remove 0 from $R^2$. Therefore I wouldn't be using d operator on a compactly supported form (though I think d operator is necessary). So this just may not work...

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: By cohomology, do you mean de Rham cohomology?  What tools for computing cohomology are you familiar with?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I am only familiar with the process of taking exterior derivatives.

Comment: Ignoring the word compactly supported: can you compute the cohomology?

Comment: no not in detail